# Checking if a particular device driver is loaded

Tags: c++, windows, drivers

I'm trying to work out if I can check if a particular video card device driver is loaded in Windows Server 2003 using C++. Can anyone give me pointers on how I might achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **EnumDeviceDrivers** - there's an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682619%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the link - quick question though, where do I get psapi.h from?

Comment: It's part of what Microsoft call the Platform SDK - it should be part of recent MS development environments and it is also available separately from MS.

Comment: Hi Neil,

I'm getting the following error when trying to compile the example you linked to;

Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetDeviceDriverBaseNameW@12 referenced in function _main DriverChecker.obj DriverChecker

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: GetDeviceDriverBasename is part of the same library as EnumDeviceDrivers, so if one works, so should the other - I'm afraid I don't have an answer to this!

Comment: Sorry, the other one isn't working either - should have included that too;

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetDeviceDriverBaseNameW@12 referenced in function _main

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EnumDeviceDrivers@12 referenced in function _main

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432745/visual-studio-c-link-with-psapi-lib check this for solving your problem.